# How can I keep track and control which views deallocates?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, avplayer, dealloc

When my app is launched, it starts out at a custom `UIViewController` with a custom `UITableView` with custom `UITableViewCells`. The cells can play videos, among other things. I'm using `AVPlayer` and `AVPlayerLayer` to play the videos. This initial view controller also has a menu-popup, which can take you to another controller. When another menu-option is clicked, the initial `UIViewController` deallocates. This is on purpose, and setting the new `UIViewController` as the applications `rootViewController`. However, if I start playing a video in a cell in the initial viewController and then click a menu-option, the video keeps playing in the background, I can still hear the audio.

I have simply put

```
-(void)dealloc{
    NSLog(@"Initial controller deallocated");
}
```

in the initial view controller to confirm that it deallocs when I set the new controller as root, and this prints out, but the video still keeps playing.

I have now 'overridden' the `-(void)dealloc`(like above) methods of both the custom `UITableView` and the custom `UITableViewCell`'s, but neither of these fires.

I have simplified the explanation of the hierarchy here, and I believe there could be other connections holding on to the tableView(mostly because I don't know any other reason for this behavior).

I believe, however, that these possible connections all are under the initial view controllers hierarchy, and it is my understanding that the entire hierarchy under a view controller will vanish when the view controller does. Is the `AVPlayer` a reason the tableView and/or cell won't dealloc? The videos playing are over internet, and I can also tell that the app continues downloading and buffering the video after the controller has been deallocated. I have tried setting the player, the playerLayer and the entire cell to `nil`, but it keeps downloading, and I'm thinking I have misunderstood some connections.

First of all, I think properties with `(strong, nonatomic)` or `(nonatomic, retain)` might have something to do with these. I don't completely understand where to use what, so I almost exclusively use this. Of what I'm reading, `weak` seems to be correct for some of these references, but I'm also 'scared' of the implications, as I don't completely understand them.

Second, in my custom `UITableView`, I have a property: `@property CustomCell *playing;`.

When I start playing a video in a specific cell, like this;

`[someSpecificCell.player play];` I also do this: `self.playing = someSpecificCell;`. Now I can later easily find the cell that's playing, I.E to stop it. When I later try to deallocate the cell, I use `self.playing = nil;`, however, this does not deallocate the cell. Why not? Am I simply removing the reference from tableView? Does this mean there are other references?

**Is there a way to see a list of where these references are /from?** As far as I know, all references are in the same initial hierarchy, yet somehow some parts of the hierarchy stays alive after their controller has deallocated.

---

**Update**

I've now tried to launch **Instruments** with the Allocations-tool, and I don't completely understand what I'm seeing.
The hierarchy I've created is something like this:

```
MyNavController1->MyViewController1->MyView1->MyTableView1->MyCell1->text&video etc.
```

When I click another menu-option, I create another (almost identical) hierarchy, setting the **new** MyNavController(2) as rootViewController for the app. The 'current' hierarchy will now be

```
MyNavController2->MyViewController2->MyView2->MyTableView2->MyCell2->something else
```

When I present the new hierarchy, and set this new hierarchy as rootViewController to the app, the first hierarchy is supposed to be deallocated. In `-(void)dealloc` of both `MyNavController1` and `MyViewController1` print out "Deallocated" with `NSLog();`, and nothing from `MyTableView1` and `MyCell1`.

In **Instruments** it says that `MyViewController` is `#living: 1, #transient: 1`, which I'm guessing means the first deallocated correctly.
When I check the field for `MyTableView`, it says `#living: 2, #transient: 0`, which I'm guessing means the tableView isn't deallocated, as my previous "research" found.
However, in the list showing the two instantiations of `MyTableView`, it says that the responsible caller of the first tableView(which is supposed to be deallocated, but isn't) is the first `MyViewController1`, which is confirmed deallocated. What does this mean?

If I further click the Address field of this specific `MyTableView`(the first), it says:

```
#     Event Type      ΔRefCt:     RefCt     ...     Responsible Caller
0     Malloc          +1          1         ...     'MyViewController1'
```

What does this really mean, and can I find out where a possible reference is held?

Comment: have you tried using the allocations tool in Instruments? this would be a good place to start. you can see a list of all retains and releases applied to an object, telling you why it's still in memory

Comment: Setting self.playing to nil, just sets your pointer to nil, but the cell is still a subview of the table view which retains it. It would be helpful to see your table view code to see how you are adding the player.

Comment: @rdelmar Oh okay, so I'm not setting the actual value of the cell to nil, thanks. It would take a lot of time to show the tableView-code as it's A LOT of code, and somehow messy. The custom cell is adding the player though, not the tableView. Now that I mention it, I recall having made some delegate-methods between the cell, the tableView and the controller for starting and handling the video.. I'll check that out. EVEN SO, I find it weird that not all references are removed when the initial controller is changed. I'll check out Patrick Goley's suggestion after christmas, thanks.

Comment: If your delegates are strong, you could have a retain cycle that keeps things from being deallocated.

Comment: @rdelmar Looks like the delegates are all `(nonatomic, assign)`, but I don't have the time right now to check everything, and I haven't read up on the meaning of nonatomic, atomic, assign, strong, weak etc, so I don't know if this value will cause a retain cycle. I might also have other 'strong' references other than the delegate-refs. I will however read up on it when I get the time after christmas. If you think this is causing the problem I'm having, feel free to write a small explanation as an answer, and I'll accept it later if/when I confirm that the references are in such a cycle. Thanks

Comment: What are you really trying to accomplish by doing this?

Comment: @uchuugaka I am trying to move from ViewController A to B, and deallocating every view associated with controller A. My status now is that I have an AVPlayer playing a video file deep within the ViewController A's hierarchy, which is still playing its video after Controller A is deallocated. Some of the views within controller A's hierarchy are not deallocating, and I am 'really trying to accomplish' a form of solution to help me find out what I've done wrong, and which references I have to manually set to nil, if that indeed is the problem. I'm sorry if that wasn't clear in my question.

Comment: ah, I see. Retain cycles indeed.

Comment: basically, trying to track it in dealloc won't help you much. You should use Instruments to watch things happen and then you'll be able to see what calls are not working. Basically, somewhere, something still has a strong reference to something it should  not have.

Comment: @uchuugaka I've now tried something in Instruments, and updated my question. Would you mind taking a look? Thanks